# How to make a discourse plugin available for public posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, discourse

I've developed a discourse plugin successfully. However, I need to be logged in into discourse in order to see the plugin working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclosure: user [@dariomac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126519/dariomac), the question owner, is part of our organization.

You have to skip the ensure_logged_in in the before_filter of the controller. Add something like this line to your plugin controller:

skip_before_filter :ensure_logged_in, only: :